# How to Post data to Slack using NodeJs using axios?

Tags: node.js, slack

I am trying to understand an asynchronous function, to convert it into synchronous type for a use case,
The function is making a Post request to Slack using Node's https module,
I wish to convert this code to use the `axios` library.

I am unable to understand what exactly is the Post Body being sent to the endpoint.

**Function code as below -**

```
function postToSlack(logTitle, logMessage, logType, context) {
    var payloadStr = JSON.stringify({
        'username': slackBotUsername,
        'attachments': [
            {
                'title': logTitle,
                'fallback': logMessage,
                'text': logMessage,
                'color': getLogTypeColour(logType)
            }
        ],
        'icon_emoji': slackBotIconEmoji,
    });

    var options = {
        hostname: 'hooks.slack.com',
        port: 443,
        path: slackPostPath,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(payloadStr),
        }
    };

    var postReq = https.request(options, function(res) {
        var chunks = [];
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            return chunks.push(chunk);
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            var body = chunks.join('');

            if (res.statusCode < 400) {
                console.info('Message posted successfully');
            } else if (res.statusCode < 500) {
                console.error("Error posting message to Slack API: " + res.statusCode + " - " + res.statusMessage);
            } else {
                console.error("Server error when processing message: " + res.statusCode + " - " + res.statusMessage);
            }

            if (completedRequests++ == totalRequests - 1) {
                context.succeed('DONE');
            }
        });
        return res;
    });

    postReq.write(payloadStr);
    postReq.end();
}
```

I want to know if,
**options** is the raw request post body?,
or is `options` just used to construct the **endpoint** and **headers**?

Is my understanding correct that there is no Post request body,
But just an https `endpoint` and `headers`?

**Reference -**
https://flaviocopes.com/node-http-post/

Answer (score 5):

**Sample to POST to Slack with Node.js (using axios)**

You should be able to accomplish the same thing with axios with something like...

```
'use strict';

const axios = require('axios').default;

const main = async () => {
    try {
      const data = 'Hello World ! ';
      const payload = {
        attachments: [{text: data, color: 'green'}]
      };
      const options = {
        method: 'post',
        baseURL: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        data: payload
      };
      await axios.request(options);
    } catch (e) {
      const status = e.response.status;
      console.error(`There was an error, HTTP status code: ${status}`);
    }
  }
}
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

**payloadStr** is the request body, the **options** object is setting things like the path of the request and the headers, most of which would be automatically set by axios.

You should be able to accomplish the same thing with axios with something like...

```js
function postToSlack(logTitle, logMessage, logType) {
  const payload = {
    username: slackBotUsername,
    attachments: [
      {
        title: logTitle,
        fallback: logMessage,
        text: logMessage,
        color: getLogTypeColour(logType)
      }
    ],
    icon_emoji: slackBotIconEmoji,
  };

  axios.post(slackPostPath, payload)
    .then((response) => {
      console.info(`Message posted successfully: ${response}`);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(`Error posting message to Slack API: ${error}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set:

- <slack_webhook_url>
- <channel_name>
- <your_message>

here:

```
try {
    var response  = await axios({
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': <slack_webhook_url>,
        'data': '{"channel": "#<channel_name>","username": "webhookbot","text": "<your_message>", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}'
    });
        console.log('slack response');
        console.log(response);
} catch(error) {
    console.log('error slack response');
    console.log(error);
}
```